# How to add product in cart from SalesRule_Model_Validator in magento

Tags: magento

I have created one custom promotion rule in which i am giving a free product if customer spent over X amount 
so, i have tried this code for adding a product in cart but unable to add a product.

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);

$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Can anyone suggest any code to add a product in cart from validator.php

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.I implemented below code in validator.php. It worked in my case.

```
$productToAdd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');                        
$productToAdd->load('productid');
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
/* @var $cart Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart */
if ($productToAdd->getId()) {
  $cart->addProduct($productToAdd, 1);                            
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav

This works for me.

i want to increase answer ratings but i dont have enough reputation poins.

Thanks Again